# IllegalStateException in ListView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview, sqliteopenhelper

I have a listview in my main activity which shows the detail info about a person when we click on it and I have two classes

EmployeeList.java - http://pastebin.com/5vPMKrCQ

DatabaseHelper.java - http://pastebin.com/NS7RR8E6

I have the following exception in my logcat.

```
05-09 16:58:10.278: E/CursorWindow(23310): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 3 columns.


05-09 16:58:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(23310): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: where you get error i mean on click of listview ?

Comment: @Samir Yes while clicking only

Comment: check count `autocursor.getCount()`

Comment: @SamirMangroliya 05-09 17:34:43.728: I/System.out(4678): 2

Comment: your mean you get two row from autocursor>

Comment: @SamirMangroliya As i already specified 2 rows, 3 columns.

Comment: no one answer accepted by you

Comment: @Satheesh go to your profile and accept it again because if someone giving answer that means he wants you to accept or upvote his ans if it helps you a bit

Comment: @SamirMangroliya I have fixed the issue. The problem is  i hav used officephone in query where as my column name is officePhone :) Simple thing took hours :)

Comment: @Satheesh se my answer is also correct for how to get data from database///

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Confused between Upvote and Accept Answer. Jus now got clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from employee_directory where _id " + id);

    if (null != cursor&&cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            String title= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TITLE));

            String membername= currsor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.MEMBER_NAME));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you have not done **cursor.moveToFirst()** after getting values into the cursor from database.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
    setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
//Your logic
                    }
                }
```